# ExoPlayer - play two audio tracks simultaneously

Tags: android, exoplayer

Using `ExoPlayer` i'm trying to play two audio tracks simultaneously.
My idea was to create two  `MediaSource`, and  to "combine" between them using `MergingMediaSource`.
This is what I have done:

```
    Uri uriAudio1 = Uri.parse(AUDIO_URL_1);
    Uri uriAudio2 = Uri.parse(AUDIO_URL_2);

    MediaSource audioSource1  = new ExtractorMediaSource(uriAudio1, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, mainHandler, null);
    MediaSource audioSource2  = new ExtractorMediaSource(uriAudio2, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, mainHandler, null);


    MergingMediaSource mergedAudioSource = new MergingMediaSource(audioSource1, audioSource2);


    mPlayer.prepare(mergedAudioSource);
```

How ever instead of hearing both audio tracks in parallel, i hear only the first `audioSource1`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set channel count like this

```
val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector()
trackSelector.setParameters(
                trackSelector.buildUponParameters()
                .setMaxVideoSizeSd()
                .setMaxAudioChannelCount(2)
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this functionality isn't currently supported, [according to issue #2200](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2200#issuecomment-288524442).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, solved it by using two different instances of Exoplayer, one for each audio asset, and playing them at the same time.

Answer (score -5):

You can use ConcatenatingMediaSource :

```
  List<MediaSource> mediaSources = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Track track : tracks) {
                        MediaSource mediaSource = ...//use your uri media source from tack.getPath
                        mediaSources.add(mediaSource);
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.prepare(new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSources.toArray(new MediaSource[mediaSources.size()])));
```

Comment: A concantenating media source plays two MediaSources after each other, not simultaneously.